# Create user and add more fields with webapp2_extras.auth

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I have a simple webapp2 Auth+Session example here: https://github.com/coto/webapp2_auth (AppEngine + Python2.7)

I can't add more attributes (for example email) to User Entity when I create a new user.

Can anyone help me? Is there a way to do it by using user_attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the answer is add params to create_user method like this:

`user = self.auth.store.user_model.create_user(username, password_raw=password, mail=email, shoes = "Chile", ip="120.12.34.123")`